# How is proportionality involved in this expected value problem?

Tags: probability, integration, probability-distributions

I have tried to solve this problem:

Two people randomly think of a real number between 0 and 100. What is the expected difference between their numbers?

A hint given says that one has to use the information to express a  'proportionality relationship'.

I have tried looking at smaller cases, but don't see how I can set up a proportionality relationship.

How can I do so?

Answer (score 0):

We have two numbers between $0$ and $100$. Let the left number be $X_{L}$ and the right number be $X_{R}$ (for example, suppose two numbers be 30 and 11. $X_{L}=11, X_{R}=30$).

Let $Y = X_{R}-X_{L}$. The **CDF** of random variable $Y$ is as follows:

$$F(Y< y) = \frac{y}{100}$$

We know for any positive random variable $Z$, $E[Z] = \int \big(1- F_{Z}(z)\big)dz$. Thus, we have
$$E[Y] = \int_{0}^{100}\big(1-F_{Y}(y)\big)dy = \int_{0}^{100}\big(1-\frac{y}{100}\big)dy = 50$$